# Masked Autoencoder Structure

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, autoencoders

In the following structure when we use MADE due to the constraints for making a masked autoencoder, it seems some inputs do not have any connection to the next layer, and also there is the output that does not have a connection to the previous layer!

Can someone clarify?

[image]

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange. Rather than asking "Can someone clarify?", can you please reformulate this in order to ask a more **specific** question? Is your question "In MADE, is it true that some inputs are not connected to the next layer and some outputs not connected to the previous layer?" Moreover, can you please clarify where you took this screenshot from and provide a paper or article that introduces this "MADE" (for people not familiar with it).

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your consideration, this is the official paper link: https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03509 @nbro